# How to solve Update environment operation is complete, but with errors. For more information error in AWS Elasticbeanstalk

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am using AWS Elasticbeanstalk for my project.When I uploading new version app it is giving error

```
Update environment operation is complete, but with errors. For more information, see troubleshooting documentation
```

My IAM role has AWSElasticbeanstalkFullAccess

Then why I am getting this error.
Thank in advance

Comment: did you ever figure this out? im running into the same issue after updating the AMI to a custom AMI i created.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue.

I did the following and it worked.

- From Elastic Beanstalk environment page, I chose to Rebuild the environment (**Actions > Rebuild Environment**)
- Deployed the new application version.

Answer (score 2):

A number of things can result in this, including issues with .ebextensions files.

Troubleshooting tends to be iterative, since logs are frequently not created or inaccessible.

Things to try:

- Roll back to a previous application version and verify any changes to .ebextensions are valid
- **Rebuild the environment** (Actions -> Rebuild Envrionment) in the EB console. This frequently enables EBs log snapshot facility to recover such that you can get further insight into what might be amiss.

Comment: ...sort of the AWS equivalent of rebooting a Windows box. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can try digging what the error exactly was by getting the [logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.logging.html) of the event in the 'eb-engine.log' file. In my case I got [this error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57282839/how-to-fix-error-pg-config-executable-not-found-on-elastic-beanstalk-permanentl) and follow one answer to solve it. You can try 'eb logs' command also to get detailed info.