# How to fix Error: pg_config executable not found on Elastic Beanstalk permanently

Tags: django, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a Django project that works with PostgreSQL on Elastic Beanstalk. 
I have found the next error when deploying:

```
Error: pg_config executable not found.

pg_config is required to build psycopg2 from source. 

Please add the directory containing pg_config to the $PATH or specify the full executable path with the option:

python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...
```

I followed [psycopg2 on elastic beanstalk - can't deploy app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33747799/psycopg2-on-elastic-beanstalk-cant-deploy-app/34957820#34957820) to solve it and it worked! BUT after a while Amazon seems to update my virtual env and the error returns so I have to go back and do the same stuff over and over again.

I also have tried configuring the database instance directly from the Elastic Beanstalk panel but nothing changes.

The database is on RDS and I think it's important to say that when I manually install psycopg2 on my instance and re-deploy everything works fine, I even have made a couple of deploys after that and the problems is not there but it is after a while.

I really want to know how to solve it once for all. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36189852

Answer (score 17):

It is trying to do is build the postgres drivers from source.
You can deal with this several different ways. For example, you can choose to install the drivers from a binary package instead of building them from source.

in your requirements.txt, replace

```
psycopg2==2.8.5
```

with

```
psycopg2-binary==2.8.5
```

If, you do insist on building it from source when you deploy to Beanstalk, you will need to use platform hooks to pre-install the dependencies that are needed to compile it. The AL2 instances are pretty bare-bone, so you will need to do roughly the following:

- add directory structure .platform/hooks/prebuild
- in prebuild, create a script, something like '10_install_dependencies.sh'
- at the top of the script you will need #!/usr/bin/sh

Use this script to add needed dependencies. For example, for the posgres development libs you will want

```
sudo yum install -y <yum-packahe-that-you-need>
```

You may also end up having to install other development libs needed to build psycopg...

Comment: thanks a lot; using `psycopg2-binary` worked nicely

Comment: for me using psycopg2-binary==2.8.5 fix the issue but if I go to latest 2.9.1 it start failing again. Thanks.

Comment: Where do you add the structure? .platform/hooks/prebuild